# Move One Element From one list to another In haskell

Tags: haskell

Morning i was doing an exercise it's my first time in Haskell
The exercise is to move the first element from my second list to the first position of my first list

Result: test [] [4,2,5,7]
=>  ([4], [2,5,7])

```
That is my code :
test ::[a] -> [b] -> ([a],[b])
test [] [] = ([], [])
test [x] [] = ([x], [])
test [] [x] = ([x], [])
test [y] [x] = ([x:y], [])
But i got errors so please help me
```

this is my error

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[b]’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          pa :: forall a b. [a] -> [b] -> ([a], [b])
        at Pushswap.hs:30:6
    • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘y’
      In the expression: x : y
      In the expression: [x : y]
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: b (bound at Pushswap.hs:34:9)
        y :: a (bound at Pushswap.hs:34:5)
        pa :: [a] -> [b] -> ([a], [b]) (bound at Pushswap.hs:31:1)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: Please tell us what the errors are. By which I mean, please paste them exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the implementation

```
test [y] [x] = ([x:y], [])
```

`y` is of type `a`, `x` is of type `b` and `[x:y]` needs to be of type `[a]`, hence the error.

You should be able to get past this error by making both lists the same type.